# How to improve my jumble game(shelve)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I took my basic Word jumble game and added some additional features to learn new stuff.

```
import random
#from amazement import *
import shelve

# Welcome the player
print("""
    Welcome to Word Jumble.
        Unscramble the letters to make a word.
""")

def wordlist(file):
    with open(file) as afile:
        global the_list
        the_list = [word.strip(",") for line in afile for word in line.split()]

def menu():
    print("1--Play the game")
    print("2--Browse a word set")
    print("3--Add a new word set")
    print("4--Delete a word set")
    print("5--My sorted scores")
    print("6--Exit")
    pick = int(input("Pick one:"))

    if pick == 1:
        shelf = shelve.open("wordlists.dat")
        for key in shelf.keys():
            print(key)
            # print(shelf[key])
        word_set = input("Pick one:")
        global wordlist
        wordlist = shelf[word_set]
        game()

    elif pick == 2:
        browse()

    elif pick == 3:
        global name
        name = input("Name: ")
        filename = input("File name:")
        add_list(filename)

    elif pick == 4:
        delete()

    elif pick == 5:
        score()

def browse():
    print("Retrieving word list from shelf")
    shelf = shelve.open("wordlists.dat")
    for key in shelf.keys():
        print(key)
    name = input("Which one?")
    print("Your words: {}".format(shelf[name]))
    shelf.close()
    return menu()

def game():
    global score
    score = 0
    for i in range(4):
        word = random.choice(wordlist)
        theWord = word
        jumble = ""
        while(len(word) > 0):
            position = random.randrange(len(word))
            jumble += word[position]
            word = word[:position] + word[position + 1:]
        print("The jumble word is: {}".format(jumble))

        # Getting player's guess
        guess = input("Enter your guess: ").lower()

        # congratulate the player
        if(guess == theWord):
            print("Congratulations! You guessed it")
            score += 1

        else:
            print("Sorry, wrong guess.")
    print("You got {} out of 10".format(score))
    shelf = shelve.open("score.dat")
    shelf["score"]=[score]
    shelf.sync()
    shelf.close()
    return menu()

def score():
    shelf = shelve.open("score.dat")
    for key in shelf.keys():
        print(shelf[key])
    #print(shelf["score"])
    shelf.close()

def add_list(file):
    with open(file) as afile:
        the_list = [word.strip(",") for line in afile for word in line.split()]
        print(the_list)
    print("Shelving Lists ...")
    shelf = shelve.open("wordlists.dat")
    shelf[name] = the_list
    shelf.sync()
    shelf.close()
    print("Success.")
    print("Retrieving word list from shelf")
    shelf = shelve.open("wordlists.dat")
    print("Your words: {}".format(shelf[name]))
    shelf.close()
    return menu()

def delete():
    shelf = shelve.open("wordlists.dat")
    for key in shelf.keys():
        print(key)
    delete_key = input("Do you want to delete:")
    if delete_key == key in shelf.keys():
        del shelf[key]
        shelf.sync()
        shelf.close()
    else:
        print("Please type in the correct file")
        return delete()
    return menu()
#filename = "words/amazement_words.txt"
# wordlist(filename)
menu()
# game()
```

Now I have some questions to more experienced coders here.

First, when a user selects a word set to play with he needs to type in the word set. I was thinking it would be easier to add a number to the key, for example:

```
1-amazement
2-sad
```

Words are added to the game with this function:

```
def add_list(file):
    with open(file) as afile:
        the_list = [word.strip(",") for line in afile for word in line.split()]
        print(the_list)
    print("Shelving Lists ...")
    shelf = shelve.open("wordlists.dat")
    shelf[name] = the_list
    shelf.sync()
    shelf.close()
    print("Success.")
    print("Retrieving word list from shelf")
    shelf = shelve.open("wordlists.dat")
    print("Your words: {}".format(shelf[name]))
    shelf.close()
    return menu()
```

So is it possible to give the key an automated number prefix?

Second problem with shelve: when I play the game the score is recorded. At the end of the game it is saved into score.dat. It works if I exit the programme and run it again. But if I want to look at the score when the programme runs, after I finish the game, I get the following error:

```
File "jumble_game.py", line 128, in <module>
    menu()
  File "jumble_game.py", line 33, in menu
    game()
  File "jumble_game.py", line 88, in game
    return menu()
  File "jumble_game.py", line 48, in menu
    score()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Also I want to keep last 10 scores but it only keeps the latest one now.

Any other suggestions how to improve it(especially code structure and re-usability - should I use modules?) would be very appreciated as I am a total beginner.

Thanks!

Comment: You might be looking for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), where you can get guidance on how to improve your code. SO is for code issues rather than reviews.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in Code Review; there isn't a sufficiently specific programming question.

Comment: Indeed, I overlooked global score. It works now, thanks :) Will post it later on Code Review.

Comment: I'd help with some of the code fixes, but it's hard to figure out how the game works with no documentation, and so many paths to crash.  I did eventually get to play once.